# Backbone fetch model then render view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

When performing the fetch operation on a model, I can see the API returning the desired data in JSON format. Console logging the model shows the new data in a 'changed' object.

Before and after fetch:

```js
Object {
  cid: "c1",
  attributes: Object,
  _changing: false,
  _previousAttributes: Object,
  changed: Object,
  id: undefined,
  _pending: false
}

Object {
  cid: "c1",
  attributes: Object,
  _changing: false,
  _previousAttributes: Object,
  changed: Object[1],
  id: undefined,
  _pending: false
}
```

The data is obviously being fetched, and it is present in the model. However, when rendering it, the default values are displayed.

```
App.Models.Document = Backbone.Model.extend({

  defaults: {
     id: '',
     owner: 0,
     created: '',
     lastupdate: '',
     content: 'Default document content'
  },

  url: '/api/'

});


App.Views.DocumentView = Backbone.View.extend({

  tagName: 'textarea',
  className: 'editor',

  template: App.Template('editortemplate'),

  initialize: function() {

  // As proposed in so many similar questions
  this.listenTo(this.model, "change", this.render);

  },
  render: function() {

    this.$el.html( this.template( this.model.toJSON() ) );

    $(".app-content").html(this.$el);

    return this;

  }
});


a = new App.Models.Document();
a.fetch();
b = new App.Views.DocumentView({ model: a });
b.render();
```

How do I update the view properly with the new data?

If I remove the defaults from the model, 'content' is not defined.

Comment: It's weird that `changed: Object` changes to `changed: Object[1],`. What is the structure of data returned from API? BTW id is a special attribute used by backbone.

Comment: The returned data is a json object

[{ 
"id":"1",
"owner":"1",
"created":"2016-04-30 21:57:23",
"lastupdate":null,
"content":"Successful API fetch"
}]

Comment: This means that you need to implement either `parse()`  to process the response before Backbone sets it to the model attributes or you need to fetch from that REST resource from a [`Collection`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backbone.Model expects an object to be returned from the server, not an array. An array should be returned in the case of a collection.

So in your case you need to define a `parse` method to return the object containing the data:

```js
App.Models.Document = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    owner: 0,
    created: '',
    lastupdate: '',
    content: 'Default document content'
  },
  url: '/api/',
  parse: function(response) {
    return response[0];
  }

});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this hint!

Answer (score 2):

You can listen for the Backbone `sync` event on the model. `sync` fires after a successful call to the server

```
this.listenTo(this.model, 'sync', this.render);
```

Also you can move your model fetch to `App.Views.DocumentView`, in the initialize method. 
Than, on success you render the view:

```
App.Models.Document = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    id: '',
    owner: 0,
    created: '',
    lastupdate: '',
    content: 'Default document content'
  },

  url: '/api/'
});


App.Views.DocumentView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: 'textarea',
  className: 'editor',
  template: App.Template('editortemplate'),
  initialize: function() {
    var self = this;

    // model fetch
    this.model.fetch({
      success: function() {
        // call render
        self.render();
      },
      error: function () {
        // handle error
      }
    });

    // As proposed in so many similar questions
    this.listenTo(this.model, "change", this.render);
  },
  render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    $(".app-content").html(this.$el);
    return this;
  }
});


var myModel = new App.Models.Document();
var myView = new App.Views.DocumentView({
  model: myModel
});
myView.render();
```

Comment: Thanks Yosvel. Unfortunately, nothing really changed.
The default value is displayed. The fetch is performed, and the model object has a 'changed' value that I still cannot access.